# Is it possible to change font size for telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot and want to send text in a bigger font. How is it possible to do so using node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is limited support of HTML and Markup in Telegram, but it is not possible to increase the font size. [See Formatting Options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options).

One option is to use bold and italic to achieve a nice formatting (see example in Python)

```
update.message.reply_text('Some *boldtext*' and some _italictext_',
                          parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
```